# Use Different HTTP Protocols per Browser in Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, apache2, http2

I am trying to use http/2 for everything except Safari because of some strange behavior we are seeing when using http/2 with any version of Safari we have handy. I cannot figure out how to set up Apache to allow it, however. Can anyone shed some light on why the following doesn't work?

```
BrowserMatchNoCase Safari NOHTTP2
# Chrome includes both Safari and Mozilla in its User Agent
BrowserMatchNoCase Chrome !NOHTTP2

<IfDefine NOHTTP2>
    Protocols http/1.1
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !NOHTTP2>
    Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
</IfDefine>
```

That is currently in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/http2.conf`. I have no experience with `IfDefine` or `BrowserMatch`, so I'm not sure if I am doing this correctly (given that it isn't working, it would seem I am not). Every browser I test it on still has http/2 enabled with the above config as well as any others I have tested.

I have also tried `SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent` instead of `BrowserMatch`, and various options other than `IfDefine` such as `If` and `Directory`, but all of these throw "Protocols not allowed here" errors when running the configtest.

I am running Apache 2.4.25 on Debian 9.6.

Comment: I think that proper approach would be to fix the Safari issue, because I don't see any HTTP/2 issues with any Safari I have around me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you can't do what you want because by the time you've worked out what browser the client is using you've already negotiated the protocol and received a request; the User-Agent is submitted as a request header.

Your first `<IfDefine>` block would only work if you ran the `httpd` binary passing `-DNOHTTP2` as an extra argument and that would restrict the protocol to HTTP/1.1 for all clients. Because the define is unset it's defaulting to the second block which is enabling all of the protocols. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#ifdefine

Comment: After quite a bit of testing last week, I have come to this same conclusion and your explanation makes complete sense. It's unfortunate because I cannot figure out how to solve the Safari issue, but it does seem correct